# The file casper/filesystem.squashfs is corrupt

Tags: 12.04, iso

I tried burning Lubuntu 12.04 to a CD-RW with Xfburn and braseo, but it keeps be corrupted. I tried to check my hashes but:

```
Lubuntu 12.04 i386$ md5sum -c md5sum.txt | grep -v "OK$"
md5sum: ./casper/filesystem.squashfs: Input/output error
./casper/filesystem.squashfs: FAILED open or read
md5sum: WARNING: 1 listed file could not be read
```

My disc has enough room. Also, the iso's checksum is fine.

```
~/Desktop$ md5sum -c MD5SUMS.txt
md5sum: lubuntu-12.04-alternate-amd64+mac.iso: No such file or directory
lubuntu-12.04-alternate-amd64+mac.iso: FAILED open or read
md5sum: lubuntu-12.04-alternate-amd64.iso: No such file or directory
lubuntu-12.04-alternate-amd64.iso: FAILED open or read
md5sum: lubuntu-12.04-alternate-i386.iso: No such file or directory
lubuntu-12.04-alternate-i386.iso: FAILED open or read
md5sum: lubuntu-12.04-alternate-powerpc.iso: No such file or directory
lubuntu-12.04-alternate-powerpc.iso: FAILED open or read
md5sum: lubuntu-12.04-desktop-amd64+mac.iso: No such file or directory
lubuntu-12.04-desktop-amd64+mac.iso: FAILED open or read
md5sum: lubuntu-12.04-desktop-amd64.iso: No such file or directory
lubuntu-12.04-desktop-amd64.iso: FAILED open or read
lubuntu-12.04-desktop-i386.iso: OK <--------------------------------This is the file
md5sum: lubuntu-12.04-desktop-powerpc.iso: No such file or directory
lubuntu-12.04-desktop-powerpc.iso: FAILED open or read
md5sum: WARNING: 7 listed files could not be read
```

What is going on?

Answer (score 1):

Input/output error is not uncommon at the very end of a CD.
(Caused often by write type "TAO", which creates two non-data blocks
at the end of the range, which the drive advertises as readable.
Aka "Read-ahead bug". Traditionally made harmless by 300 kB of padding.
It should not happen if you have chosen write type "SAO".)

Make sure that you try to read only as many bytes from the CD
as are stored in the original .iso image file.

The size of an ISO image is supposed to be integer divisible by 2048.
E.g. if your .iso file has a size of 4,581,523,456 bytes, then it
has 2,237,072 blocks. So use

dd if=/dev/sr0 bs=2048 count=2237072 | md5sum

(assuming your CD drive has address /dev/sr0)

When the reading is done (hopefully without i/o error), then
lookup the resulting MD5 checksum in your file "md5sums.txt".
E.g. "a87d2796b7acf90fbe48dcaeb27dc7cc"

Command line example for writing CD with write type SAO:

xorriso -as cdrecord -v /dev/sr0 -sao -eject lubuntu-12.04-desktop-i386.iso

The same option will also work with programs cdrecord or wodim,
instead of "xorriso -as cdrecord".

Comment: Actually, I think it was a disc scratch. I new CD-R fixed it.